# Redis Windows Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379 but appilcation is working

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, ioredis

I am having an issue with my nodejs-redis-docker-compose application. The application ran normally for a few times. But later, it started giving me the following error. I am using `redis-server v3.2.100` `docker 18.09.1 build 4c52b90`. I uninstalled docker and redis and re-installed them but I still have the same problem. Here is the error.

```
REDIS_DB | 1:C 22 Jan 2019 02:24:00.208 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
REDIS_DB | 1:C 22 Jan 2019 02:24:00.208 # Redis version=5.0.3, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
REDIS_DB | 1:C 22 Jan 2019 02:24:00.208 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
REDIS_DB | 1:M 22 Jan 2019 02:24:00.210 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
REDIS_DB | 1:M 22 Jan 2019 02:24:00.210 # WARNING: The TCP backlog setting of
511 cannot be enforced because /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn is set to the lower value of 128.
REDIS_DB | 1:M 22 Jan 2019 02:24:00.210 # Server initialized
REDIS_DB | 1:M 22 Jan 2019 02:24:00.210 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues
with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
REDIS_DB | 1:M 22 Jan 2019 02:24:00.211 * DB loaded from disk: 0.001 seconds
REDIS_DB | 1:M 22 Jan 2019 02:24:00.211 * Ready to accept connections
MAIN_API    | [nodemon] starting `node --trace-warnings index.js`
MAIN_API    | Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
MAIN_API    |   <rejected> { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
MAIN_API    |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
MAIN_API    |     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
MAIN_API    |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
MAIN_API    |     syscall: 'connect',
MAIN_API    |     address: '127.0.0.1',
MAIN_API    |     port: 6379 } } reason: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
MAIN_API    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
MAIN_API    | Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
MAIN_API    |   <rejected> { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
MAIN_API    |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
MAIN_API    |     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
MAIN_API    |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
MAIN_API    |     syscall: 'connect',
MAIN_API    |     address: '127.0.0.1',
MAIN_API    |     port: 6379 } } reason: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
MAIN_API    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
MAIN_API    | ✓-- Redis client pid=>37 Connected
MAIN_API    | --- Redis server pid=>37 is ready
MAIN_API    | ~~~ Testing local redis storage...
MAIN_API    | ✓-- Redis pid=>37 startup test succeeded
MAIN_API    | ✓-- MongoDB pid=>37 Connected
MAIN_API    | ✓-- Server pid=>48 running at port: 5555
MAIN_API    | Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
MAIN_API    |   <rejected> { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
MAIN_API    |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
MAIN_API    |     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
MAIN_API    |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
MAIN_API    |     syscall: 'connect',
MAIN_API    |     address: '127.0.0.1',
MAIN_API    |     port: 6379 } } reason: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
MAIN_API    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
MAIN_API    | Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
MAIN_API    |   <rejected> { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
MAIN_API    |       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
MAIN_API    |     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
MAIN_API    |     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
MAIN_API    |     syscall: 'connect',
MAIN_API    |     address: '127.0.0.1',
MAIN_API    |     port: 6379 } } reason: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
MAIN_API    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1117:14)
MAIN_API    | ✓-- Redis client pid=>48 Connected
MAIN_API    | --- Redis server pid=>48 is ready
MAIN_API    | ~~~ Testing local redis storage...
MAIN_API    | ✓-- Redis pid=>48 startup test succeeded
MAIN_API    | ✓-- MongoDB pid=>48 Connected
```

The error is thrown when the nodejs application is starting but it get connected to the redis server by the time the application is up and running.

Redis console log

```
[16308] 21 Jan 18:03:25.425 # Server started, Redis version 3.2.100
[16308] 21 Jan 18:03:25.426 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
[16308] 21 Jan 18:03:25.426 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

I ran `netstat -a -n -o` on my console and here is the relevant part (I believe).

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:6379           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16308
TCP    [::]:6379              [::]:0                 LISTENING       16308
```

The following are my files.

./Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.15.0

RUN mkdir -p ./usr/src/MainAPI

WORKDIR /usr/src/MainAPI

COPY ./ ./usr/src/MainAPI

RUN npm install

ARG NODE_VERSION=10.15.0
```

./docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  # Redis
  redis:
    container_name: REDIS_DB
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6378:6379"

  # API
  main-api:
    container_name: MAIN_API
    build: ./
    command: ["npm", "start"]
    working_dir: /usr/src/MainAPI
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/MainAPI
```

./redisClient.js

```js
const Redis = require("ioredis");
//module.exports = require("redis").createClient(...); => same errors with this module as well

module.exports = new Redis('redis://redis:6379/0');

//module.exports = new Redis('redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0'); =>crashes the app
//module.exports = new Redis('redis://redis:6378/0'); =>crashes the app also
```

./app.js

```js
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const { red, green, cyan, yellow } = require("kleur");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const helmet = require("helmet");

const redisClient = require("./redisClient");

const { CLIENT_BASE_URL, API_BASE_URL, MONGO_URI } = process.env;

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";

const server = express();

const whitelist = [CLIENT_BASE_URL, API_BASE_URL];
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function(origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      return callback(null, true);
    } else {
      return callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"), false);
    }
  }
};

server.use(helmet());

if (isProduction) {
  server.use(cors(corsOptions));
  server.use(morgan("combined"));
} else {
  server.use(morgan("dev"));
}

server.set("trust proxy", 1);

/**
 * Test redis storage on deploy
 */
redisClient.on("connect", function() {
  console.log(
    green("✓-- ") + "Redis client pid=>" + process.pid + " Connected"
  );
});

redisClient.on("ready", function() {
  console.log(cyan("--- Redis server pid=>" + process.pid + " is ready"));
  console.log(cyan("~~~ Testing local redis storage..."));
  const testKey = "key";
  const testValue = "value";
  redisClient.set(testKey, testValue).then(() => {
    redisClient.get(testKey, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(red("✗-- An error occured while testing redis storage"));
        console.error(error);
        return process.exit(1);
      }
      if (!result || result !== testValue) {
        console.log(
          red(
            "✗-- Redis pid=>" + process.pid + " did not pass the startup test"
          )
        );
        console.error(result);
        return process.exit(1);
      }
      console.log(
        green("✓-- Redis pid=>" + process.pid + " startup test succeeded")
      );
    });
  });
});

redisClient.on("error", function(err) {
  console.log(red("✗-- Something went wrong with redis"));
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

redisClient.on("end", function() {
  console.log(
    yellow("--- ") + "Redis client pid=>" + process.pid + " closed connection"
  );
});

mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose
  .connect(
    MONGO_URI,
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log(green("✓-- ") + "MongoDB pid=>" + process.pid + " Connected");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(red("✗--Database Connection"));
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

server.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
server.use(bodyParser.json());

require("./controlers/home")(server);
require("./controlers/user")(server);
require("./controlers/admin")(server);

if (isProduction) {
  server.use(express.static("client/build"));

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
  });
}

module.exports = server;
```

I did not call .listen(...) on the server because it is exported to another file (index.js).

Thank you

Comment: `redis:6379` should be right, using the name of the YAML block for the service as a host name and its internal port as the port number.  That won't have an IP address 127.0.0.1, though.  Can you check that you've correctly updated and rebuilt everything?

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes I removed the images and rebuilt everything but I am still getting the same error. The strange thing is that the app works fine. It is bugging to not knowing where the problem is. I tried different kinds of configuration that I found on github. They work but still getting the same exact error. I even uninstalled redis and docker and reinstalled as I said in my post. Still nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am responding to my own question. I found what is causing the issue in my code. In fact, I started using `npm agenda`, which uses `MongoDB`, for scheduling some tasks in my application. I later switched to `npm bull`, which is using `Redis`. I created the queue instance like the following.

```js
const Queue = require("bull");

const emailQueue = new Queue("emails");
```

while it should be

```js
const Queue = require("bull");

const emailQueue = new Queue("emails", {
  redis: { port: 6379, host: "redis-server" }
});
```

Because I did not specify the redis settings for the module, it was not able to connect to the server. I totally forgot that I had another module that is using redis. The reason the app seemed to be working is because `express` get connected to redis while `bull` did not. I would figure that out if I had tried to use a feature that bull is part of the process. I also simplified my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files to include only the necessary steps.

/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine # create image with NodeJS version alpine included 

WORKDIR /usr/app # set working directory of the app to be /usr/app/. create folder /usr/app if it does not exist already. The following operations would then happen inside /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./ # copy package.json file into current directory, which is /usr/app according to previous step

RUN npm install # install dependencies 

COPY ./ ./ # add the rest of the files to /usr/app

CMD ["npm", "start"] # run 'npm start' when the container is starting
```

/docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  # Redis
  redis-server: # the name of the redis service becomes the host name in my application
    container_name: REDIS_SERVER
    image: 'redis'

  # API
  main-api:
    container_name: MAIN_API
    build: ./
    ports:
- "5555:5555"
```

I did not need anything else for the application to work. By simply giving the service name to `ioredis` in my application, the module will figure out where to find the server. That is said [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) in `links` section. In my case, the server name is `redis-server` so the hostname for `ioredis` and `bull` would also be `redis-server` and the port number `6379`. Thank you @DavidMaze @yeaseol, and ...

Answer (score -1):

The port is bound to `6378`, so you need to access `6378`.
And can you use hostname `redis`? (Did you set it?)
Try this:
`module.exports = new Redis('redis://{docker-server-hostname}:6378');`
or
The best option is to set a `link` to docker-compose.

```
main-api:
    container_name: MAIN_API
    build: ./
    command: ["npm", "start"]
    working_dir: /usr/src/MainAPI
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/MainAPI  
    links:
      - {your-redis-container-name}
```

Try this:
`module.exports = new Redis('redis://{your-redis-container-name}:6379');`

Comment: Inter-container connections always use the internal server port, the _second_ number in `ports:` if one is present.  You don't need a `ports:` or `links:` setting.  It seems like `redis:6379` in the question _should_ be right.

Comment: @DavidMaze @yeaseol I tried with `links` and `networks` and `depends_on`. But I am still getting the same error. It may be a problem with my windows computer, I don't know. In the last few months I started to see how it is hard to become an efficient developer while using windows machines. Thank you anyways. I will keep looking for answers.